# Enable and configure cors in Drupal

Tags: javascript, rest, drupal, cors, drupal-8

I am debugging a Drupal issue where it is used as a headless api server.

I have to make a POST request to Drupal's contact form REST Endpoint when someone submits a form in a JavaScript app.

The `API` works when I test it from a REST Client.

But when I run the same code from `JavaScript` in a browser, I am getting a cors issue.

I have made sure cors is enabled in the `sites/default/default.services.yml` file.

But the changes are not taking effect.

The following are the relevant contents of the `sites/default/default.services.yml` file

```
  cors.config:
    enabled: true
    # Specify allowed headers, like 'x-allowed-header'.
    allowedHeaders: ['*']
    # Specify allowed request methods, specify ['*'] to allow all possible ones.
    allowedMethods: ['*']
    # Configure requests allowed from specific origins.
    allowedOrigins: ['*']
    # Sets the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.
    exposedHeaders: true
    # Sets the Access-Control-Max-Age header.
    maxAge: false
    # Sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header.
    supportsCredentials: false
```

I am getting following error in browser.

```
Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

I tried to change the `sites/default/default.services.yml` to the following, but I am still getting the same problem.

```
allowedHeaders: ['x-csrf-token', 'authorization', 'content-type', 'accept', 'origin', 'x-requested-with']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for the input.

It looks like the reason why it was not working was because the Drupal installation already had the old 'Drupal Cors' module also enabled which was taking precedence.

Once I disabled it, the changes that I made to the `services.yml` started to work.

Answer (score 4):

Change the file name from `default.services.yml` to `services.yml`.
Also, the exposedHeaders property should be an array of header names, or false, but never 'true'.
src: https://www.drupal.org/node/2715637

Comment: Is there a difference between `default.services.yml` file and `services.yml` file?

Comment: I am pretty sure the `default.services.yml` is just there to serve as an example. Same as how the `settings.php` has an example `default.settings.php`